# How to make ld prefer a static library over a dynamic library on macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, ld

I am using macOS 10.13.2 and have Xcode Command Line Tools installed. There are `librocksdb.a` and `librocksdb.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`. I want to link against `librocksdb.a`. But `g++ -lrocksdb` links against `librocksdb.dylib`. Here `g++` is not from GNU gcc. It is from  Xcode Command Line Tools. I know that I can use `g++ /usr/local/lib/librocksdb.a` to make `ld` link against `librocksdb.a`. Is it possile to make `ld` prefer `librocksdb.a` over `librocksdb.dylib` with `-l` option?